# How can I create a multilingual site without variations?

Tags: 2007, language, multilingual

I am new to SharePoint but know basics.

The project has already been developed in English for the USA.
It consists of user controls, developed webparts, . . it has images, Flash players, videos, etc...

What my work is: Create two sites, one for the French and the other for Canada (English). 
I am not allowed to use Variations. So can someone help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Can you explain why you are not allowed to use variations?

If you don't use variations then you will end up having to re-write variations (or use a third party tool like Chris O'Briens [SPLanguageStore](http://splanguagestore.codeplex.com/))

You should be aware that variations do NOT translate pages and won't work with custom web parts and user controls, unless you have specifically used Variation labels, although I understand these are not the best controls Microsoft has ever used!

If you need to use something other than variations then i think you are stuck with rolling your own, or using something like Google Translate to auto-translate the whole page.  I personally think that this will give aweful page translations.

Comment: Well the client doesnt agree to use varitaions . As they had sme awful experience with the variation in the past . they said variations had loads of drawback . So we r nt goin ahead with tat .

Comment: much of the problems with variations has been fixed in subsequent hotfixes. I agree that site variations were unfinished when the product was released, and its by far perfect now but much better than before the patches.

Answer (score 2):

In SharePoint 2007 every site collection and website is tied to a language, it cannot be changed dynamically. So you have to rebuild a new site collection for each language (French and Canadian one).

Furthermore you'll have to adopt you custom controls and web parts to use resource files. By this way you could use your controls and web parts for every language. The only thing you have to do is providing a resource file for each language you want to support.

Comment: ya i have planned to craete a new site collections for both sites seperately .
ur approach seams to be the one which i m suppose to follow . .

Answer (score 0):

You can have sitecollections for French and Canada apart from the USA Site Collecton

Comment: can u please ellobrate on this ?

Comment: You already have a sitecollection called USA
Add the other ones also, But these are not synchronised like we do in variations